# I accidently clicked erase disk and install ubuntu what happened to all my partitions

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, windows-10, partitioning

I had three partitions before installing ubuntu on my system now i only see one what happened to my other partitions and the data they held. If its possible i would like to view that data.

Comment: TestDisk doesnot worked for me at all.

Comment: PhotoRec didnot worked for me either